# Группировка по неделям

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Есть 2 столбца: дата и числа.
Как можно сгруппировать таким образом:

```
месяц  |  1 неделя      |     2 неделя   |    3 неделя   | 4 неделя
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Январь |  Max(1 неделя) | Max(2 неделя)  | Max(3 неделя) | Max(4 неделя)
```

Имеются в виду недели месяца. Используется Oracle SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Пусть ответ и старый, но это можно сделать с помощью [PIVOT](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/pivot.php)

```
WITH SAMPLE AS (
  SELECT sysdate       as AMOUNT_DATE, 10 as AMOUNT FROM dual UNION
  SELECT sysdate       as AMOUNT_DATE, 50 as AMOUNT FROM dual UNION
  SELECT sysdate       as AMOUNT_DATE, 30 as AMOUNT FROM dual UNION
  SELECT sysdate - 30  as AMOUNT_DATE, 10 as AMOUNT FROM dual UNION
  SELECT sysdate - 150 as AMOUNT_DATE, 10 as AMOUNT FROM dual UNION
  SELECT sysdate - 30  as AMOUNT_DATE, 10 as AMOUNT FROM dual UNION 
  SELECT sysdate - 70  as AMOUNT_DATE, 10 as AMOUNT FROM dual UNION
  SELECT sysdate - 60  as AMOUNT_DATE, 10 as AMOUNT FROM dual UNION
  SELECT sysdate - 30  as AMOUNT_DATE, 10 as AMOUNT FROM dual UNION
  SELECT sysdate - 500 as AMOUNT_DATE, 10 as AMOUNT FROM dual)
SELECT
  *
FROM (
  SELECT
    *
  FROM (
    SELECT s.AMOUNT,
           to_char(s.AMOUNT_DATE, 'W')              WEEK_DATE,
           INITCAP(to_char(s.AMOUNT_DATE, 'MONTH')) MONTH_DATE
    FROM   SAMPLE s) 
    PIVOT (MAX(AMOUNT) for WEEK_DATE in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)))
```

Вывод:

---

```
  MONTH_DATE       1       2       3       4      5
  -----------------------------------------------------
    July        (null)  (null)  (null)    10    (null)
    June        (null)    10    (null)    10    (null)
    April       (null)    10    (null)  (null)  (null)
    August      (null)  (null)    50    (null)  (null)
    March       (null)  (null)  (null)    10    (null)
```

В выводе получится максимальное значение за неделю в месяце вне зависимости от года.

Answer (score 0):

Создать вспомогательный курсор с номерами недель (что Вы имеете в виду под "неделя", не совсем ясно: или календарная неделя (1-52) или неделя от заданной даты, или ещё что) с группировкой по неделям, а затем сформировать нужную запись из этого курсора.

Comment: Имеются ввиду недели месяца

Answer (score 0):

В MSSQL примерно так

```
DECLARE @StartDate datetime
SET @StartDate = GetDate()
SET @StartDate = dbo.StartOfMonth(@StartDate)
SELECT i.ID,
       DATEADD(DAY,i.ID-1,@StartDate) AS [Date]
INTO   #Temp    
FROM   tmp_Index i
WHERE  i.ID BETWEEN DAY(@StartDate) AND DAY(dbo.EndOfMonth(@StartDate))

SELECT MAX(ID),
       DATEPART(week,[Date])
FROM   #Temp
GROUP  BY DATEPART(week,[Date])

DROP TABLE #Temp
```

Comment: Ну GetDate() -- это вряд ли то, что надо @Zida, но это уж ему видней. А далее, если я правильно понял его вопрос, как в http://hashcode.ru/questions/54368/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B

Comment: GetDate тут для примера, вся задача - тут:

SELECT
    MAX(ID),
    DATEPART(week,[Date])
FROM #Temp
GROUP BY DATEPART(week,[Date])

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать банально так без сводных таблиц и т.д.:

```
select distinct to_char(t.date1, 'Month') as monthname,
      max1, -- first week
      max2, -- second week
      max3, -- third week
      max4 -- forth week
from test t
  left join 
      (select trunc(date1, 'mm') as monthdate,
           max(case when date1 between trunc(date1, 'mm') and trunc(date1, 'mm')+7 
                    then num else null end) as max1,
           max(case when date1 between trunc(date1, 'mm')+8 and trunc(date1, 'mm')+14 
                    then num else null end) as max2,
           max(case when date1 between trunc(date1, 'mm')+15 and trunc(date1, 'mm')+21 
                    then num else null end) as max3,
           max(case when date1 between trunc(date1, 'mm')+22 and trunc(date1, 'mm')+28 
                    then num else null end) as max4
       from test
       group by trunc(date1, 'mm')
      ) m on trunc(t.date1, 'mm') = m.monthdate
```

[Пример на sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6932f/16/0).